# Using Akka ActoRef as Map key

Tags: scala, hashmap, akka

I would like to use `ActorRef` as a `Map` key. However, as `Akka` makes a temporary actor when sending messages I can't use `sender()` as the key.

Is there anyway to get the *real* `ActorRef` from the sender of the message?

Comment: The `ActorRef` you get from `sender` is a new actor ("tmp" in path), not the actual sender of the message.

Comment: I am just coming by in couple of days after the answer. Is there any reason you do not accept it as a correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look into this. I will reference akka **2.4.2** sources in this answer.

`sender()` method implementation is the following:

```
  final def sender(): ActorRef = currentMessage match {
    case null                      ⇒ system.deadLetters
    case msg if msg.sender ne null ⇒ msg.sender
    case _                         ⇒ system.deadLetters
  }
```

Moreover please note that *sender* is property of internal **message** which is used in akka. So unless you send messages like this:

```
self.tell("no sender here", null)
self ! ("no sender here", null)
```

sender parameter will be provided by akka itself:

```
  final def tell(msg: Any, sender: ActorRef): Unit = this.!(msg)(sender)
```

Now, the only question to be answered is the implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in order to make sure `ActorRef` can be stored in `HashMap`:

```
  final override def hashCode: Int = {
    if (path.uid == ActorCell.undefinedUid) path.hashCode
    else path.uid
  }

  final override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case other: ActorRef ⇒ path.uid == other.path.uid && path == other.path
    case _               ⇒ false
  }
```

So as you can see `equals` and `hashCode` hardly rely on **path of an actor**. Now what is actor path:

```
"akka://my-sys/user/service-a/worker1"                   // purely local
"akka.tcp://my-sys@host.example.com:5678/user/service-b" // remote
```

So in case your **sender** can be from actor system of another host (**remote case**) you are totally fine because host and port name are being used. Now to the **local case**: akka makes sure that your paths are **unique** within local actor system which means that there will be no actors with the same name.

**So answering your question**: yes, you can store results of the **sender()** method in **HashMap** as a key.

Hope it helps, sir!

Comment: It helps to be sure that `sender()` can be used as a key. However, the `ActorRef` received via `sender()` is _not_ the same as the `ActorRef` of the actual sender. Akka creates a temporary actor. So since, I construct my maps with the _real_ `ActorRefs` the keys will never match.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Could you please specify source of the following fact: "the actorref received via sender() is not the same as the actorref of the actual sender". Because I basically proved in the answer that it is wrong statement :) Or please explain what do you mean by that.

Comment: The final solution was to simply to pass `self`via the message, and with your answer we know that we can safely use it as a key.